# Gfortran: Treat pure functions as normal functions for debugging purposes?

Tags: debugging, fortran, gfortran

I need to debug some `pure` functions in a fortran Program compiled with gfortran. Is there any way to ignore the `pure` statements so I can use `write`, `print`, etc. in these `pure` functions without great effort?
Unfortunately it is not easly possible to just remove the `pure` statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a macro and use the `-cpp` flag.

```
#define pure 

pure subroutine s
 print *,"hello"
end
```

Comment: I just added the flags `-cpp` and `-Dpure=` to my compiling command. Really great idea!

Comment: For `elemental` routines in Fortran 2008, you can use `-Delemental="IMPURE ELEMENTAL"`. The capital letters are use to avoid recursive macro substitution. It works since Fortran is case insensitive.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use the pre-processor for this task:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
subroutine test(...)
#else
pure subroutine(...)
#endif
  ! ...
#ifdef DEBUG
  write(*,*) 'Debug output'
#endif
  ! ...
end subroutine
```

Then you can compile your code with `gfortran -DDEBUG` for verbose output. (In fact I personally do not set this flag globally, but via `#define DEBUG` at the beginning of the file I want debug).

I also have a MACRO defined to ease the use of debugging write statements:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define dwrite write
#else
#define dwrite ! write
#endif
```

With this, the code above reduces to:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
subroutine test(...)
#else
pure subroutine(...)
#endif
  ! ...
  dwrite (*,*) 'Debug output'
  ! ...
end subroutine
```

You can enable the pre-processor with `-cpp` for `gfortran`, and `-fpp` for `ifort`. Of course, when using `.F90` or `.F`, the pre-processor is enabled by default.