# Gfortran: Treat forall blocks as do blocks

Tags: debugging, fortran, gfortran

I need to debug a program that includes `forall` blocks. Inside of them are `pure` subroutines or functions. In order to temporarily disable the `pure` predicate I use the C precompiler as in the following question posed by me:

[Gfortran: Treat pure functions as normal functions for debugging purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037789/gfortran-treat-pure-functions-as-normal-functions-for-debugging-purposes)

The problem now is, that if the subroutines or functions inside the `forall` block are not `pure` I get an error compiling. Is there a possibility to treat these errors

```
Error: Reference to non-PURE function 'pvkp' at (1) inside a FORALL block
```

only as warnings or is there maybe an easy possibility to use the C precompiler for turning

```
forall (i=1:n)
   ...
end forall
```

into

```
do i=1,n
   ...
end do
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Given that `forall` [doesn't do what it was supposed to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122099/do-fortran-95-constructs-such-as-where-forall-and-spread-generally-result-in-fa/4141572#4141572) (and also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602596/fortran-forall-restrictions)), why not just replace all `forall` with `do` anyway?

Comment: I completely understand the concept of `forall`. I believe that the `forall` blocks will actually improve the speed of my program (once it  is debugged).

Comment: I hope you plan on *testing* your assertion and not running with it purely on belief. In any event, you may want to check your assembler output to ensure that it is indeed using `forall` and not just transforming it into `do...enddo`.

Comment: I second Kyle's comment. `forall` probably won't speed-up your code, they only make it shorter. Compilers are very good at optimizing do-loops and `forall` is sometimes too difficult to do without a temporary array.

Comment: There are some situations like `forall (i=1:3) A(i,i) = 1.0 end forall` where a `do` loop would be optimized by the compiler as good as the `forall` assignment. But I have some other cases, where I use `pure` functions that actually do more complicated stuff. Of course, `forall` is just an array definition and that’s how I use it. There is this construct for this task, so why not use it?
Can you give me a hint on how to check how the blocks in question are optimized?

Comment: *There is this construct for this task, so why not use it?* Because it has been shown to not be as effective as the designers had hoped, as stated in my first comment. You'd have to read the assembler output (`gfortran -S file.f90` will do it) and compare the two cases.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Can you give a reference where is has been shown that `forall` blocks are not as effective as the designers had hoped? (I can’t really understand in which cases a `do` block would be optimized better than a `forall` block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simplification is to use a `do concurrent` loop instead of a `forall` block.  This reduces the number of linked changes required in the code: one need only change the loop specification, not change an `end forall` to an `end do`.

An approach not to be proud of, using `cpp`, and suitable for only simple cases:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define conloop(var, lower, upper) do var=lower, upper
#else
#define conloop(var, lower, upper) do concurrent (var=lower:upper)
#endif

  conloop(i,1,n)  ! Either a DO or DO CONCURRENT depending on DEBUG
  ...
  end do
end
```

The above does have the obvious extension to using a `forall` construct (with the extra `#define` for the ending) if that is really what you want.  Alternatively, although more tedious to produce, using such things as

```
#ifdef DEBUG
do i=1,n
#else
forall (i=1:n)
#endif
  ...
#ifdef DEBUG
end do
#else
end forall
#end
```

This is horrible, but I imagine that's true for all pre-processor approaches.  It does allow more complicated masks and is more localized.

Comment: And as Kyle Kanos says, one gets readable code by just sticking with `do` except in the rare cases where the compiler doesn't do a good job.

Comment: I ended up defining a `conloop` and an `endconloop`.